# How do I use a struct element in a for loop?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, structure

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to make a program that prompts the user to input info about 8 vocalists, which are then sorted into text files based on what the vocalist.genre input was. However, I'm having a problem when I try to use the for loop for the Users' inputs. What should I do ?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

struct vocalists
{
    public string name;
    public string origin;
    public string vocalist_type;
    public string genre;
};

public class test
{

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    vocalists vocalists1;
    vocalists vocalists2;
    vocalists vocalists3;
    vocalists vocalists4;
    vocalists vocalists5;
    vocalists vocalists6;
    vocalists vocalists7;
    vocalists vocalists8;
    
    //Vocalists inputs

    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the vocalists {0} name: ", i);
        //Here I'm supposed to do something in the format of vocalistsi.name=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the vocalists {0} origin: ", i);
        //Here I'm supposed to do something in the format of vocalistsi.origin=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the vocalists {0} type: ", i);
        //Here I'm supposed to do something in the format of vocalistsi.type=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the vocalists {0} genre: ", i);
        //Here I'm supposed to do something in the format of vocalistsi.genre=Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: What behaviour you are expecting?

Comment: Instead of having 8 variables use an array

Comment: Like @juharr I would advise using an array or List instead of doing it like the way you do. But if you insist on using variable names you can google for "Reflection in C#".

Answer (score 1):

You can't access fields by name composition, so having 8 fields isn't a good idea; you can, however, have a single field that is an array or list:

```
List<Vocalist> vocalists = new List<Vocalist>();
// now use vocalists.Add(...) and vocalists[i]
```

or

```
Vocalist[] vocalists = new Vocalist[8];
// now use vocalists[i]
```

---

I should also note that having `Vocalist` as a `struct` is a terrible idea that *will hurt you*. It should probably be a `class`:

```
class Vocalist
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Origin {get;set;}
    public string VocalistType {get;set;}
    public string Genre {get;set;}
}
```

or *at worst* be a `readonly struct`.

Comment: I know...I don't want to use struct either but since this is for a project the instructions specifically state that a struct must be made for the vocalists.

Comment: @FedonKotsakis is this a student thing? honestly, whoever wrote those instructions ... well, I'll be kind and say "quite possibly has some misunderstandings"; if it *is* a student thing, please feel free to point your tutor at me if they want to know why this is so wrong.